# How to rerender Angular Component?

Tags: angular, angular-material, rerender

I have an issue with that Angular do not update `@ViewChildren` field.
In component I have the following `html` view:

```html
    <audio-player #audioPlayer
                  ...>
    </audio-player>
```

and the following code:

```js
export class CustomDetailsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
    ...
    @Input() customDetails: <Type>;

    @ViewChildren('audioPlayer') audioPlayers!: QueryList<AudioPlayerComponent>;
    ...
}
```

After update of main field `customDetails` of `CustomDetailsComponent` `audioPlayers` still is not updated.
`audioPlayers` depends on number of audio files in `customDetails` component.

Is there a way to rerender `CustomDetailsComponent` completely ? Because for me it looks like that `@ViewChildren('audioPlayer')` calculated only once at component creation ...

Comment: I can see that your component implements `OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy` - can you show all relevant logic of the component? And all the template please. It is really hard to read the tea leaves.

Comment: Your best would be to reproduce it on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Keep in mind that change detection only runs for @Input if there *reference* changes. If `customDetails` is an object, and you're updating a property of that object, change detection will **not** be run. You would have to pass in a new object or array instead.

Comment: You could test if the viewchildren are detected by doing `@ViewChildren('audioPlayer') set audioPlayers(value: QueryList<AudioPlayerComponent>) { console.log('viewChildren', value); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually helped me is the following code:

```js
export class CustomDetailsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
    ...
    _customDetails!: <Type>;

    @Input({ required: true })
    set customDetails(value: <Type>) {
      this._customDetails = value;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }

    get customDetails() {
      return this._customDetails;
    }


    @ViewChildren('audioPlayer') audioPlayers!: QueryList<AudioPlayerComponent>;
    ...
}
```

Because `audioPlayers` depends on number of components in `customDetails`, I decided to add setter for `customDetails` and run `cdr` for changes detection, and it helped !!

Of, this Angular dependency management in Angular is not so intuitive, most time it detects changes, but sometimes not, and you fight with it :)

Answer (score 0):

If customDetails is an object type,it will not set off change detection because of its mutability. Make sure you're passing the values correctly in that case with {...passedObject}, to make it an immutable copy and not a pointer towards same memory, to be able to set off any change detections. If that's not it, please show some more code logic.